# Apache Tomcat Environment Variables

Tags: tomcat, solr

When I deploy my .war file into Tomcat from my IDE I define that:

```
-Dsolr.solr.home=/home/vicita/Desktop/lucene-solr/solr/solr_h 
-Dsolr.data.dir=/home/vicita/Desktop/lucene-solr/solr/solr_h/data
```

However when I deploy it into a remote machine I have to define that parameters. The book that I follow says that I have to define that into $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost within an xml file:

```
<Context path="/solr" docBase="/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/solr.war" debug="0" crossContext="true">
    <Environment name="solr/home" type="java.lang.String" value="/usr/share/solr_h/" override="true"/>
</Context>
```

by the way:

```
/usr/share/solr_h
```

is my directory that I should mention. The first thing that I want to know I didn't define a variable like solr.solr.home at here?

Second thing that my .war could not find that folder and throws error. I tried to create setenv.sh and put:

```
-Dsolr.solr.home=/usr/share/solr_h
-Dsolr.data.dir=/usr/share/solr_h/data
```

However when Tomcat starts it says:

```
/usr/share/tomcat/bin/setenv.sh: line 1: -Dsolr.solr.home=/usr/share/solr_h: No such file or directory
/usr/share/tomcat/bin/setenv.sh: line 2: -Dsolr.data.dir=/usr/share/solr_h/data: No such file or directory
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/java/default
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
```

Any ideas to fix it?

Comment: Where is the solr install on the remote machine ?? do the paths /usr/share/solr_h exists and the user tomcat is running with have rights to that folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xml file that is under localhost had a different name from my .war file. I assigned same name to it as .war's and it has resolved.